# Can my damaged Braun electric toothbrush with Duracell batteries explode?

Tags: batteries, safety

I have a Braun toothbrush with 2 Duracell AA LR6/MX15000 (brand name Turbo Max), and today, the battery lid on the toothbrush broke, so I'm fearing that water might get in, and cause an explosion? I've just started using the batteries, so they're fully charged.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have no background in electrical engineering whatsoever, and I'm worried about the safety.

I don't really care if the toothbrush or batteries die for good, I'll get a new one next time I see it in the store.

[image: broken lid]
[image: the toothbrush]

Comment: Highly unlikely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Don't worry. The worst thing that can happen is your appliance stops working.

Maybe you'll find someone that will say that there's a little chance of it explode, etc. But the chance of explosion is the same chance of one asteroid falling over your house, and if it happens the toothbrush is the lesser thing that you could worry. ;-)

With only two cells and with the kind of chemicals those cells use, there's no risk of explosion, neither of electric shock.

Don't be afraid: just put some glue or tape to close this gap and keep the water to get inside (it will be very ugly) and keep using it, if you want. It will not harm you, period.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, taping it up.

Comment: Hey, a small update: I wanted to replace the batteries today, opened the cartridge, and found out that water did get inside, the batteries leaked some gross brown stuff, but hey, there was no explosion.